# Using a for loop to generate dynamically named variables with properties

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var imageLocations = [["grass", "grs.gif"], ["wood", "wd.gif"], ["sand", "snd.gif"]];

for (var i = 0; i < imageLocations.length; i++) {
          tiles[imageLocations[i][0]] = new Image();
          tiles[imageLocations[i][0]].src  = imageLocations[i][1];
          console.log(tiles);
};
```

My desired output from this code is:

```
tiles.grass.src = "grs.gif";
tiles.wood.src = "wd.gif";
etc.
```

The actual output I am getting:

```
tiles.grass = [0, "grs.gif"];
tiles.wood = [1, "wd.gif"];
etc.
```

My question is how do I prevent the array index from being added to the object properties as well? And why is the src property being ignored?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. `tiles` becomes an object that contains `HTMLImageElement` instances with the `src` that you want.

Comment: Works for me! I am getting an image element for `tiles.grass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is going on over there, but the below code works for me:

```
var imageLocations = [["grass", "grs.gif"], ["wood", "wd.gif"], ["sand", "snd.gif"]];

var tiles = {};

for (var i = 0; i < imageLocations.length; i++) {
          tiles[imageLocations[i][0]] = new Image();
          tiles[imageLocations[i][0]]['src']  = imageLocations[i][1];          
};

console.log(tiles);
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6s01q1n/5/

Comment: This cant work as you are trying to use an array `[]` with key value paires, which should be an object `{}`.

Comment: @somethinghere It will work because arrays are objects. But it's true that `{}` would be better.

Comment: @somethinghere It does actually work but you're right, I messed that up

Comment: What is your solution? I don't see any meaningful difference. The `['src']` syntax offers no benefit over `.src` and is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @Whathaveyoutried yeah, I guess this wont really throw an error as javascript just molds it to what it needs, but it probably wouldnt work in strict. It does work, though. And squint, the solution is qdding q stqrting vqriqble to store everything in. I think. Otherwise there is no difference, no...

Comment: @somethinghere: That's just an omission in the question. The OP is describing output that would be impossible if the `tiles` object hadn't actually been defined.

Comment: @squint at least it explains why people say they are unable to duplicate the problem. Also, switching from AWERTY to QWERT is doing my head in.

Comment: @somethinghere: Yes, but that should be a comment, not an answer. Questions with no clear problem statement should be improved or closed, not answered. This isn't going to be helpful to anyone in the future.